# Resize event of child class of UserControl doesn't get called

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, resize

I am trying to design a UI in C# and I am having some problems with the events of one of my child classes.

Basically, I have a class ("WidgetWindow") that inherits from `Form` and, in the scheme of things, is a **mdiChild** to the main form.

Next, I've defined an "**IWidget**" base class that inherits from `UserControl` and from which the actual widgets are built (they inherit this class).

I have three types of widgets and, for two of them, the resize event gets called correctly, whenever the parent "**WidgetWindow**" class gets modified, but no event gets called for the third one, except the Load event.

Do you have any tips as to how I can investigate the reason? I am pretty new to `.NET` so I may be doing something wrong.

```
public partial class WidgetWindow : Form
{
    IWidget ctl;
    private Point desiredLocation;
    private Size desiredSize;

    public WidgetWindow()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        InitializeComponent();

        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.ResumeLayout();
    }
    public WidgetWindow(IWidget ctl, Point location, Size size)
        : this()
    {
        this.desiredLocation = location;
        this.desiredSize = size;

        this.Location = location;
        this.Size = size;
        mainContainer.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width - 10, this.Size.Height - 10);
        mainContainer.Location = new Point(5, 5);                

        if (ctl != null)
        {
            this.ctl = ctl;                
            ctl.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width - 10, this.Size.Height - 10);
            ClientSize = ctl.Size;                
            ctl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            mainContainer.Controls.Add(ctl);
            ctl.refreshMy();
        }            
    }   
}   

public partial class IWidget : UserControl
{
    // TODO Add it in the future
    public virtual event EventHandler<TableDataChangedEventArgs> DataChanged;

    protected TableModel data;
    protected bool initialized = false;

    public IWidget()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public virtual void refreshMy()
    {
        ;
    }       
}

public class DigitalReadOut : IWidget
{
    internal System.Windows.Forms.Label lblValue;

    internal System.Windows.Forms.Label lblCaption;

    private int MDID;
    private int SDID;
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // DigitalReadOut
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.Name = "DigitalReadOut";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    public DigitalReadOut(int MDID, int SDID)
    {

        this.MDID = MDID;
        this.SDID = SDID;
    }      

    public override void refreshMy()
    {
        this.lblCaption = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblValue = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        //this.SuspendLayout();
        //
        //lblCaption
        //
        this.lblCaption.AutoSize = false;
        this.lblCaption.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.lblCaption.Name = "lblCaption";
        this.lblCaption.TabIndex = 0;
        this.lblCaption.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.lblCaption.ForeColor = Color.GreenYellow;
        this.lblCaption.BackColor = Color.Black;

        //
        //lblValue
        //
        this.lblValue.AutoSize = false;
        this.lblValue.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.lblValue.Name = "lblValue";
        this.lblValue.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.lblValue.TabIndex = 1;
        this.lblValue.Text = "###";
        this.lblValue.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.lblValue.ForeColor = Color.GreenYellow;

        //
        //DigitalReadOut
        //
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblValue);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblCaption);            
        this.Name = "DigitalReadOut";

        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

        Redraw();

    }

    private void Redraw()
    {
        Control c = this;
        Graphics g = c.CreateGraphics();

        //if we are going to do autosizing of a text box font do it here...
        lblValue.Left = 0;
        lblValue.Top = 0;
        lblValue.Height = (int)(0.66 * (float)c.Height);
        lblValue.Width = c.Width - 3;

        this.lblCaption.Left = 0;
        this.lblCaption.Top = lblValue.Bottom;
        //Makes the top of the Caption under the value readout
        this.lblCaption.Width = c.Width - 3;
        this.lblCaption.Height = (int)(0.33 * (float)c.Height - 3);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblCaption.Text))
            return;

        StretchTextValue();
        StretchText();

    }
```

PS: Adding the `Resize` event handler for the **IWidget** class works correctly, the same for the other two classes which inherit it.

Comment: Unrelated: `I am pretty new to .NET` - You might want to have a look at XAML-based technologies (such as WPF or WinRT XAML) instead of winforms. winforms is a really old technology and the general consensus is that it's not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications, which makes it look like it doesn't make sense to learn winforms, in 2014.

Comment: Could you please show us the code that is generating the problem? it is a bit hard to guess what is going wrong.

Comment: I've attached the code to the main post. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so I've managed to "hack" my way around this by adding my `Resize` handler to the list of resize handlers of the `WidgetWindow` class. Not very pretty, but it works.